# Trying to connect to Twilio video room with screen sharing

Tags: twilio

I've been researching methods to design a new application around Twilio's "Screen Capture on Chrome" guide here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/screen-capture-chrome

I've successfully created a Chrome extension, published it and was able to share a screen and connect it to a Room.

What I'm hoping someone can help with is getting another user to connect and view the shared Room (shared screen).

I've shared my screen via the following code (snipped for length) and verified via the Twilio console that it is indeed connected:

```
const room = await connect(twToken, {
    name: 'marty',
    tracks: []
  });

  const stream = await getUserScreen(['screen'], chrmExID);
  const screenLocalTrack = new LocalVideoTrack(stream.getVideoTracks()[0]);
```

I've then created a test site accessed by a second system to connect to the room above.
I've tried different methods, but the second user never seems to see the shared video in the room. 
For example:

```
const remoteDiv = document.getElementById('bodyScreen');
 room.participants.forEach(participant => {
participant.tracks.forEach(track => {
            remoteDiv.appendChild(track.attach());
          });
```

Debugging via Chrome, I see that the forEach is trying to enumerate on an undefined object.

I've also tried some of the ASP.NET C# solutions Twilio has on GitHub, but I seem to be having mismatch issues between the Twilio NuGet packages and the twilio-video.min.js I'm using

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I am currently writing a blog series about building an application like this, but it's not done just yet. However, I might be able to help a little here.

When you join a room, as well instantly enumerating the existing participants and their tracks, you should also listen for each [participant's `trackAdded` event](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0/docs/Participant.html#event:trackAdded). Tracks may not connect as soon as a participant is connected, so listening on that event will receive any tracks that are added after the participant has joined the room.

```
room.participants.forEach(participant => {
  participant.on('trackAdded', track => {
    remoteDiv.appendChild(track.attach());
  });
});
```

Like I said, I am still working on and writing up my experiences here, so keep an eye on the [Twilio blog](https://www.twilio.com/blog/) for when the series is published.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thanks for this, I discovered it a few days ago and tried it out, works great! I hit another snag though, which I've listed here which should hopefully help. When Twilio video connects to a room, it enumerates available devices on the system. If it finds none (which would be a valid case for the receiver of a screen share) it throws an error and stops. I got the other user to also share their screen to the room, which allowed Twilio video to connect successfully and then attach my screen share track. Link to discussion on GitHub here: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/issues/137

Comment: Thanks for reporting that, it's interesting to see how `getUserMedia` behaves in this situation. Perhaps using [`navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices) is a good thing to attempt before trying to connect with both video and audio selected?

Comment: Cheers, I'll try that. Probably best to catch any issues at enumerateDevices before sending anything else down the pipe